# Cannot export to CSV from SQL without changing the format of the data?

Tags: sql-server, excel, windows, powershell

What I am trying to do is very simple.

I have PS script that extracts data from the SQL server and saves the output in CSV format.
For the column PartNo, there is no defined format so it is all over the place. Most of values extract fine except for the ones in the format of "xxxx-x-x" get converted to "x\x\xxxx".

The cells could be formatted in Excel but that does not work because that is how the data shows up in the first place. Formatting the cells doesn't work.

Also, the output is correct in the terminal; it only messes up when exported to CSV

How do I stop this from happening, I need the data to be exactly how it is in the SQL table.

I am using:

- Windows 10 22h2
- MS SQL Server 2005
- PowerShell Ver 7.2.11
- Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054)

Code is below

```
Import-Module ImportExcel
$dataFile = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Desktop\Scripts\Aras\Copy of Part RN Sample Export - 11-11-23.xlsx"
$server = "ServerName"
$database = "DatabaseName"
$csvFilePath="C:\Desktop\Scripts\Aras\CSVOutput\Output_EngParts.csv"
#Write-Host $dataFile.PartRn
ForEach ($partRnItem in $dataFile){
    Write-host $partRnItem.PartRN
    $partRn = $partRnItem.PartRN
    $queryEngParts = "SELECT  [PartRn], [PartNo], [Title], [CompanyId] FROM [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[EngParts] WHERE PartRn = $partRn"
    $invokeSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $queryEngParts 
    $invokeSql | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: SQL 2005? Good grief, it's time to upgrade my friend.

Comment: So you're saying if, in SSMS, you run the query `select PartRn, PartNo from dbo.EngParts where PartRN = 19946` you get a `PartNo` of `2045-2-2` but when you open the CSV you're creating from those results with `Export-Csv` the value is `2/2/2045`?

Comment: @Xedni yes, exactly. The results are also correct in the terminal of VS Code. Using SSMS 18 though.

Comment: So what does it look like if you open the csv file in, say, notepad++ (or even notepad)? somewhere where Excel doesn't have a chance to mangle the data?

Comment: @Xedni oh damn!! Format looks good in NotePad ++ but rows repeat, in Excel they don't, weird.  The end user needs this in Excel though

Comment: Excel is "helpfully" trying to interpret the data type. Try concatenating a single quote mark before the data it has decided is a date to force Excel to accept it is text. Alternatively, Excel reads the first few rows of text to make the datatype decision so try including a row with a value that cannot be interpreted as a date as the first record.

Comment: I have had some success using the `ImportExcel` module. `Find-Module -Name ImportExcel` https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from our comments, the good news is, your data *is* being generated correctly, and you just have to get it into Excel without it being mangled. I'm not an excel guru, but I can think of two ways you could do this.

First, open the generated CSV in notepad++ and copy everything (CTRL+A, CTRL+C). Then open a blank Excel document and hit Past -> Text Import Wizard

[![Text Input Wizard][1]][1]

That will bring up a dialog which will allow you to set your data types as excel is parsing your CSV. I just tested this on my machine with one of the codes you said was getting improperly formatted, and it maintained it after doing it this way. Just make sure to set the "column data format" to "text" when you get to that part.

The other option is you could create a blank excel document *first* and format all the columns with the data types you want. That too should retain the data in its proper format.

This is a bit of a pain either way since you have to do manual work for each CSV you create, but maybe it will get you started, and give you some ideas to run with.

If you need to have the data as an excel file, maybe look into a process for outputting the contents of SQL directly to an excel file. Import/Export Wizard or SSIS might be an approach, or there might be a powershell module for the same.

If it's too onerous to have to do this for each file you're generating, maybe you could run off a *single* csv for all the `PartRn` values you care about. At least then you'd only have one excel file you need to muck with.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p750V.png

Comment: Perfect!! just exported an excel file instead of CSV and that works!

Comment: also if your data is too big to copy/paste then preformat the columns as suggested and use the `Data > Get External Data > From Text`, or you could just go direct and do the `From Other Sources > From SQL Server` option